# Parameter not given value

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ms-access

So I have an SqlDataSource which uses the following query depending on what the user inputs:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE ";

    if (make != 1)
    {
        query = query + "make_id = @make";
        SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("make", make.ToString());
    }

SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
```

When I debug this and follow through each line, when I get to the last line of my code which is "SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;" the query in the output window equals to "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE make_id = @make" this is exactly how I want it however shouldnt it have the value of the make in the SQL query rather than "@make" ?

Comment: I think you missed @ in the sql parameter

Comment: @SherifAhmed I've tried both and they don't work

Comment: Is this SQL Server, Access, SQLite, ... ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Access

Comment: Could you post any other related code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it somewhat like this and see if that works better. Note the `@make` directly in the query string.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE make_id = @make";

SearchDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
SearchDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("@make", make.ToString());
```

However, I'm more accustomed to something like this (hard to know what's needed without more code):

```
SqlCommand command = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Cars WHERE make_id = @make", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", "make value here");
```

Comment: What happens?  What kind of error messages, or what is the result?

Comment: No errors, it just gives a result when debugging that the SQL command is "SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE make_id = @make" surely it should give the actual value and say "SELECT * FROM CARS WHERE make_id = 4" ?

Comment: I don't think it necessarily does the parameter substitution before you execute the query.

Comment: Why do you need a parameter? Just do: `query = query + "make_id = " + make.ToString();`

Comment: @GDS, that creates the possibility of a SQL injection attack. Example:https://xkcd.com/327/.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update you, yes I got it working however having more problems now